# Current project specific settings effect universal settings

Tags: ide, phpstorm

I am using `PHPStorm 10.0.3` and i have configure my project to work with localhost. In the settings it says its a project specific settings and will affect current project only.

[image]

But when i close this project and open a different project it shows the same identical settings for all the projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it appears under other projects. Maybe this is IDE UI bug and it confuse you.

But you can hide it enabling `Visible only for this project` checkbox in [Deployment: Connection Tab](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/deployment-connection-tab.html).

*You can find it on screenshot from your question.*